# Swap image on click from multiple divs

Tags: jquery, if-statement, replace, swap

I have been asked to add another color option to [this page](http://cookware.lecreuset.com/cookware/content_Le-Creuset-Truckette_10151_-1_20002). If you click on the Marseille sign, the truck changes from orange to blue; if you click it again it changes back to orange. If you click the explore sign on the right, two views become available which also have the swapped image color.

I want to add a new div to the page that will make it yellow. So blue button should change from yellow or orange to blue, and then back to orange if it is clicked when blue.  Yellow button should change from blue or orange to yellow, and then back to orange.
The blue button should not make the truck turn yellow, and the yellow button shouldn't make it turn blue.

The selected color needs to persist if someone clicks Explore.

Here is the original jQuery that makes the image swap:

```
        var isOrange = true;
        $("#marseilleBtn").click(function(){
         $("img.img-swap").each(function(){
                    if(isOrange){
                        this.src = this.src.replace("_orange","_blue");
                    } else{
                        this.src = this.src.replace("_blue","_orange");
                    }
         });
         if(isOrange){
             isOrange = false;
         } else {
             isOrange = true;
         }
    });
```

I didn't write this code and I'm new to jQuery so this is challenging for me.  I wrote this code, and it almost works.  The problem is that if the yellow truck is on, and I click the blue sign, it doesn't change color. Also, if the blue truck is on, and I click the yellow sign, it doesn't change color. It will only change color if I'm starting from orange...hope that makes sense.

```
        var isOrange = true;
        $("#marseilleBtn").click(function(){
         $("img.img-swap").each(function(){
                    if(isOrange){
                        this.src = this.src.replace(("_orange") || ("_soleil"),"_blue");
                    } else{
                        this.src = this.src.replace("_blue","_orange");
                    }
         });
         if(isOrange){
             isOrange = false;
         } else {
             isOrange = true;
         }
    });

        var isOrange = true;
        $("#soleilBtn").click(function(){
         $("img.img-swap").each(function(){
                    if(isOrange){
                        this.src = this.src.replace(("_orange") || ("_blue"),"_soleil");
                    } else{
                        this.src = this.src.replace("_soleil","_orange");
                    }
         });
         if(isOrange){
             isOrange = false;
         } else {
             isOrange = true;
         }
    });
```

Can anyone help me achieve what I am trying to do? I'm open to a totally different approach if you know of something better too...went this route because I was starting from the code I was given.  I also tried to create an OR statement, but this doesn't work at all, not sure why:

```
    this.src = this.src.replace(('_orange, _yellow'),'_blue');
```

Bonus question! I'm confused by the first part of this code, that declares the variable isOrange as true, and then the if/else statement at the end that declares it false. Can anyone break that down for me? I understand the image swapping part of it...

```
         if(isOrange){
             isOrange = false;
         } else {
             isOrange = true;
         }
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE:

Working on this, but it is requiring an extra click to change color after it has been changed twice.  I.e. click Marseille, turn blue. Click Marseille, turns orange. Click click to turn back to Marseille.

```
        var color = "orange";  //first default color of img is orange
          $("#marseilleBtn").click(function(){  //on click 
             $("img.img-swap").each(function(){   // find all the images that has class img-swap ..i guess there is 3 more images there
                  if(color == "orange"){  //check if orange .. which is correct and 
                     this.src = this.src.replace("_orange","_blue"); //change it to blue
                  } else if(color == "yellow"){   //if yellow
                     this.src = this.src.replace("_soleil","_blue"); //chnage to yello
                  }else{ //if blue
                     this.src = this.src.replace("_blue","_orange"); //chnage to yellow
                  }

             });

             if(color =="orange"){
                 color = "blue";
             }else if(color == "blue"){
                 color = "yellow";
             }else{
                 color = "orange";
             }

        });

        var color = "orange";  //first default color of img is orange
          $("#soleilBtn").click(function(){  //on click 
             $("img.img-swap").each(function(){   // find all the images that has class img-swap ..i guess there is 3 more images there
                  if(color == "orange"){  //check if orange .. which is correct and 
                     this.src = this.src.replace("_orange","_soleil"); //change it to yellow
                  } else if(color == "blue"){   //if blue
                     this.src = this.src.replace("_blue","_soleil"); //chnage to yello
                  }else{ //if yellow 
                     this.src = this.src.replace("_soleil","_orange"); //chnage to yellow
                  }

             });

             if(color =="orange"){
                 color = "blue";
             }else if(color == "blue"){
                 color = "yellow";
             }else{
                 color = "orange";
             }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**updated**

```
  var color = "orange";  //first default color of img is orange
      $("#marseilleBtn").click(function(){  //on click 
         $("img.img-swap").each(function(){   // find all the images that has class img-swap ..i guess there is 3 more images there
              if(color == "orange"){  //check if orange .. which is correct and 
                 this.src = this.src.replace("_orange","_blue"); //change it to blue
              } else if(color == "yellow"){   //if yellow
                 this.src = this.src.replace("_soleil","_blue"); //chnage to yello
              }else{ //if blue
                 this.src = this.src.replace("_blue","_orange"); //chnage to yellow
              }

         });

         if(color =="orange"){
             color = "blue";
         }else if(color == "yellow"){
             color = "blue";
         }else{
             color = "orange";
         }

    });


      $("#soleilBtn").click(function(){  //on click 
         $("img.img-swap").each(function(){   // find all the images that has class img-swap ..i guess there is 3 more images there
              if(color == "orange"){  //check if orange .. which is correct and 
                 this.src = this.src.replace("_orange","_soleil"); //change it to yellow
              } else if(color == "blue"){   //if blue
                 this.src = this.src.replace("_blue","_soleil"); //chnage to yello
              }else{ //if yellow 
                 this.src = this.src.replace("_soleil","_orange"); //chnage to yellow
              }

         });

         if(color =="orange"){
             color = "yellow";
         }else if(color == "blue"){
             color = "yellow";
         }else{
             color = "orange";
         }

    });
```

and bonus answer!!! the first `var color` is the deafult color which is orange... the end if/else condition is beacuse sine youe have three images for `Explore` too .. u need a loop and in loop you are chekcing the colors... so in  first call .. orange is the color so it chnages to blue( runs the loop 3 times..) and then come to this if/else condition which changes the value color to blue...in second click. since the color is blue now.. the loop changes it to yellow......and so on..

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for this - it swaps the truck to blue when I click it, but if I click the Explore button it goes back to orange. I need it to stay the selected color when explore is clicked. I do really appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: Getting so close! I had to modify it a little bit because each button should only change between two colors instead of 3, but for some reason my change is requiring an extra click to change back to orange after the first time it is swapped. Any idea why? Updated my question with my version of your code.

Comment: ok.. updated the codes... replace this with your code and try it out.. i updated your last if conditions for both the clicked.. and you don't need `var color = "orange"; ` two time.. remove the one below

Comment: thank you! It works locally...trying on the server now. I really appreciate the help and education :)

Comment: it's close, but I keep getting an error message in IE9: backVisible is undefined.  Any chance you can help in chat? If not, no problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26479/discussion-between-surfbird0713-and-bipen)

Answer (score 0):

Well the first things which jumps to me is that you wirte the same funciton twice.

You can wirte it like this too:

```
var isOrange = true;
$("#marseilleBtn, #soleilBtn").click(function () {
    $("img.img-swap").each(function () {
        if (isOrange) {
            this.src = this.src.replace(("_orange") || ("_soleil"), "_blue");
        } else {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_blue", "_orange");
        }
    });
    if (isOrange) {
        isOrange = false;
    } else {
        isOrange = true;
    }
});
```

The `if(isOrange)else isOrange = false;` tell, what color the to swithc to. So if you want to add a third color, you can't use a simple boolean anymore, since it has only tow values. To keep the code clear, I would use a string.

Your code can look like this:

```
var curentColor = "orange";
$("#marseilleBtn, #soleilBtn").click(function () {
    $("img.img-swap").each(function () {
        if (curentColor === "orange") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_orange", "_blue");
            curentColor = "blue";
        } else if(curentColor === "blue") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_blue", "_yellow");
            curentColor = "yellow";
        } else if(curentColor === "yellow") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_yellow", "_orange");
            curentColor = "orange";
        }
    });
});
```

This will change the colors from orange to blue to yellow and then back to orange again, completing the color circle.

Comment: thank you. I updated my question to clarify - I need the blue button to change the truck from orange or yellow to blue, and the yellow button to change it from blue or orange to yellow, but each button doesn't need to cycle through all three colors.  I did try your code but i am getting syntax errors in the console.